# What is the expected size of the convex hull of $n$-points selected randomly in a $2d$-circle?

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

We know $n>2$ and worst case its a triangle, best case the points all lie on a circle. Can we generalize to higher dimensions? What's the probability that the size of the convex hull of $n$ points randomly selected in a circle is $k$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The expected number of vertices of the convex hull of $n$ points, chosen uniformly and independently from a disk, is $O(n^{\frac{1}{3}})$.

The result goes back to the 1960's.  A nice proof is in Har-Peled, "On the expected complexity of random convex hulls" (1997), from which the above sentence is quoted. ([arXiv version abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5340).)

Answer (score 0):

Amazing result! Some code for the computation-minded.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

def countVertex(n):
    points = np.random.random((n, 2))
    hull = ConvexHull(points)
    return hull.nsimplex

def testN(n, nTrial=20):
    return np.array( [ countVertex(n) for i in range(nTrial) ])

def testAllN(n_list):
    nTrial = 20
    nN = len(n_list)
    result = np.zeros((nN, nTrial))
    for i,n in enumerate(n_list):
        result[i,:] = testN(n, nTrial)
    np.savetxt('result.dat', result)

testAllN(range(5,100,5))
```

A sample result is below. The fitting line is $2.92 x^{0.318}$.
[image: sample]

Comment: The code samples random points from a unit square instead of a unit disk, but the 1/3 scaling seems to apply as well.