# Expected number of vertices in a convex hull

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution, convex-hulls

> Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed in the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$. What is the expected number of vertices that their convex hull has?

The only thing I managed to prove here was:

$$P(\text{ convex hull of }X_1, ..., X_n\text{ has exactly }k\text{ vertices}) = C_n^k P(X_{k+1}, ... ,X_n \text{ lie in the convex hull of }X_1, ..., X_n)$$

Not sure, however, whether this helps or not.

Comment: From the displayed equation, it seems that you wanted the last variable in the first line to be $X_n$, not $X_m$?

Comment: According to [this](https://members.loria.fr/SLazard/BellairsWorkshops/Bellairs-2011/problems/extreme-points.pdf), the expected number is $O\left(n^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}\right)$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346090 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37578.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected number of vertices in the convex hull is $O(n^{\frac{m - 1}{m + 1}})$ for $n \to \infty$. It was proved in 1970 by H. Raynaud in "Sur l’enveloppe convex des nuages de points aleatoires dans $\mathbb{R}_n$".

Comment: The exponent approaches 1 as the spatial dimension $m$ increases, so at a very high dimension, all points are at the surface (i.e., on the convex hull). Isn't this counter-intuitive?

Comment: @Taozi, yes, when the number of dimensions become too high, weird things tend to happen. Richard Bellman called such effects “the curse of dimensionality”.

Comment: Thanks for the keywords, I had a good time reading.